# WCF receives empty parameter consuming it through Java

Tags: java, wcf, interop, java-metro-framework

I'm having a problem with a WCF service trying to consume it from Java. The WCF is using basicHttpBinding and pretty simple definition:

```
public class MyService : IMyService
{
    public int MyMethod(MyObject obj)
    {

    }
}
```

The MyObject contains only String properties and looks like:

```
[DataContract]
public class MyObject
{
    [DataMember]
    public String Client { get; set; }

    ....
}
```

Now in Java, using Metro libaries, I'm creating the necessary classes like this:

```
wsimport -extension -keep -p com.myproject -Xnocompile http://localhost:3720/MyService.svc?wsdl
```

And finally consuming it like that:

```
MyService service = new MyService();
IMyService soap = service.getBasicHttpBindingIMyService();

ObjectFactory fact = new ObjectFactory();
MyObject obj = new MyObject();

obj.setClient(fact.createString("Someone"));

soap.MyMethod(obj);
```

Sniffing it with Fiddler it seems the data is properly sent to the service containing the "Someone" value for the Client property. Although when debugging the WCF service the Client property receives null value. Any ideas how to proceed?

Here is the SOAP message sent by the Java client:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <S:Body>
        <MyMethod xmlns="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:ns2="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MyProject.MyService" xmlns:ns3="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">
            <MyObject>
                <ns3:string>Someone</ns3:string>
                <ns3:string>123-456-789</ns3:string>
                <ns3:string>Details</ns3:string>
                <ns3:string>12345</ns3:string>
                <ns3:string>Other</ns3:string>
                <ns3:string>user</ns3:string>
                <ns3:string>2012-01-01</ns3:string>
                <ns3:string>Registered</ns3:string>
            </MyObject>
        </MyMethod>
    </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

Comment: Can you please post the traces also from you WCF service. Also the SOAP message sent from your Java client?

Comment: I tried to add some tracing to the WCF service, although I'm not sure how to properly do it and what information you expect. I've added the SOAP message at the main post.

Comment: What I saw now is that the properties of the MyObject are not named within the SOAP body. I believe this is not normal, thus my knowledge is limited.

Comment: Take a look to the WCF diag, it should tell you where the problem is. And you won't need to snif anymore ;) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx

Comment: Try http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/182406/Validating-SOAP-Message-against-WSDL and on the following one you will get a valid SOAP sample http://www.topologi.com/soapdemo/.

Comment: Vivien, I tried your suggestion and enabled the WCF tracing like that http://sho.sh/yjkC although it doesn't throw any exceptions and everything else looks normally. It seems to be a serialization/deserialization problem either on the WCF or Java side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I managed to resolve the issue. It seems the problem was within the Java code as an alternative .NET client was working properly.
The parameter's properties was incorrectly set like this:

```
obj.setClient(fact.createString("Someone"));
```

Instead the correct approach is

```
obj.setClient(fact.createMyObjectClient("Someone"));
```